# css id vs class, some thoughts

Tags: html, css

I thought that I understand id's vs classes in css documents. As far as I know there should be only one instance of id element in html document and many class elements. Now I'm looking on Microsoft driven Site.css template which is generated on every new mvc3 project and I see that there is .page element not #page ? Am I missing something here ?

Comment: if you have more than one pages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developers generally use `#id` if they are looking for applying some javascript to that element, and ID should be unique, where as `.whatever` is a class which you can use it multiple times..

As you said

Microsoft may be using `.page` because it must be applying to multiple things, so it's simply not using `#page`, it doesn't really make a difference, ya but as far as the specifity goes, `#id` selector has higher precedence than `.class`

Answer (score 1):

It's become common to only use ids for javascript, and only to use classes for CSS.

There a number of reasons behind this:

- Selecting an ID using JS is very fast
- ID have a higher specificity than a class
- It's a convenient way to split JS and CSS up

As an example:

```
<a class='btn btn-primary' id='alert' href='#'>Click Me</a>
```

Would be a typical use, where the `btn` and `btn-primary` classes are used for CSS, but the `alert` id is going to be used in JS.

That means that the link can be restyled without losing the JS link, and can have it's behaviour changed without changing its styling.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to maintain a nice cascade when using classes. Id's are a really specific way of linking style to your document. Also, at the moment you might have only one element so using id might seem the way to go but what if in the near future you are switching to two.

[CSS Specifity](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the Microsoft driven Site.css template at all; but quite frankly I wouldn't take any advice concerning CSS from them: their browser has consistently been the worst of all major browsers in terms of adopting international standards in relation to styling.

There should only be one id of any particular item on a given page; but more than one will still almost certainly work... for styling at least (try it with scripting :p).

Hell, I've just put in the microsoft homepage into the w3c

> html validator: 28 Errors, 581 warning(s)

and the w3c CSS validator

> We found the following errors (68)

Although arguably many CSS errors may be generated by quite acceptable hacks designed to fix problems in badly designed browsers... principally Microsoft's!

Even so, I'm intrigued about this Microsoft driven Site.css template: any chance you could post a link?

Just as an aditional note: ID in CSS is always given higher priority than class, regardless of order.